Is this a valid approach to use POSIX signals to set logging levels dynamically in python?
I want to be able to set python logging level to DEBUG when I am debugging the application, without stopping it.
I wrote a signal handler which toggles the level. Is this a valid approach?

_debug_enabled = False


def _toggle_debug(signum, stack):
    global _debug_enabled
    if _debug_enabled:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    else:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    _debug_enabled = not _debug_enabled


signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, _toggle_debug)

I haven't seen anyone using this approach. Is this a valid approach? Is there any pitfalls to this?

Who is the mod who closed this question as opinion based? I will find you and I will beat you to pulp with a POSIX SIGNAL HANDLER. This is not an opinion base question. I am asking what could go wrong. I am acting for facts(tm). its not an instagram post to ask for "opinions".

Using a signal handler is a perfectly valid solution! But as a general rule of thumb, please don't use global variables as they give way too much room for error. I'd use an environment variable or something like that for this. For example:
from os import environ
import signal


def _toggle_debug(signum, stack):
    _debug_enabled = environ['debug_enabled']

    if _debug_enabled:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    else:
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    environ['debug_enabled'] = not _debug_enabled  


signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, _toggle_debug)


An environment variable is essentially just a global variable that's automatically inherited by applications running in child processes. Why is that a better choice for something that only affects this script?

@Barmar in my opinion, since environment variables exist outside the code itself, they can end up preventing accidental modifications and conflicts that can happen with global variables.

Variables don't get changed "accidentally", you have to execute code that deliberately changes it. This isn't C, where you have to worry about buffer overflows that overwrite unexpected variables.
